# Rewrite rule working as intended with .php pages but not with .html pages

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I have one site where I use rewrite rules like this for aesthetic urls:

```
RewriteRule ^enroll/?$ page-enroll.php
```

This makes it so that both `http://www.website.com/enroll` and `http://www.website.com/enroll/` both redirect properly to the page.

However if I try to do something similar on another site that is an html page:

```
RewriteRule ^assisted-living/?$ assisted-living.html
```

It works for `http://www.website.com/assisted-living` but NOT for `http://www.website.com/assisted-living/`

I am getting a 404 error:

`The requested URL /assisted-living.html/ was not found on this server.`

I thought the `?` made the preceeding character optional. Why would this work with a .php file but not a .html?

Comment: Add `Options -MultiViews` at top of your .htaccess

Comment: @anubhava Thank you that worked.   Is it because in the first example the names are different? `enroll` vs `page-enroll`, but in the second they are the same, both `assisted-living` ??

Comment: Exactly, that's indeed the reason.